# Best Practices: boost::variants and standard containers

Tags: c++, boost

I'm storing a vector of values that can have a varying type determined at run time. These values will always be the same type per instance.

Which would be a better practice? Why?

```
std::vector< boost::variant<int, std::string, double> > values;
```

OR

```
boost::variant< std::vector<int>, std::vector<string>, std::vector<double> > values;
```

Answer (score 2):

The former, because it saves typing and is more flexible; your specs may change.

The latter, because it provides stronger guarantees, is more compact in terms of memory use, and may therefore be faster.

Pick according to your needs.

Comment: Faster if you're iterating for example, because you need not decide what to do with each element based on its type, but only decide at the start which type the whole vector contains.  There are probably some (but not all) cases where this would be more performant.

Comment: The second option is more compact in terms of memory, so the OP may reap the benefits of locality of reference.

Answer (score 1):

If all these instances will always be the same type then pick the second. It is semantically and directly more efficient.

Answer (score -2):

```
std::vector<BaseClass*> values;
```

Why re-invent polymorphism?

Comment: What's the base class of `int`?

Comment: This is definitely not the same as polymorphism.

Comment: @larsmans: Why, of course you'd make a holder class to contain all the things you need to store.  It could be a template class, derived from BaseClass.  You could call it VariantClass.  :)

Comment: And then you could waste your time allocating it on the heap instead of internally in the variant.

Comment: @John: yes, but then you'd like to store instances without the indirection, so you'd introduce another level of abstraction featuring a `union { int, double, BaseClass*}`, and then you'd be wondering why you re-invented `boost::variant`.

Comment: Exactly right.  To be clear, I was meaning to parody this approach given that boost::variant is already in use by the OP.  :)